# ST21i Removed boot flag

Tags: external-sd, boot, hardware, sony-xperia-tipo

I was trying to boot from the sdcard, as I thought it was a boot order issue, I disabled the boot flag on the boot partition. Now my phone will not turn on, or enter bootloader. I have found various [guides](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001546/task/android/t_faq_boot_from_usd_card_android.htm) to booting from an sdcard, however they require flipping a switch on the board, which does not appear to be there. Any ideas on how to fix this situation. I would like to be able to get the phone to a working state again, without having to wipe it.

Edit: Having looked a bit more, the phone is detected by the kernel, as it displays in dmesg and is also listed by lsusb. This is on ArchLinux 5.2.13 I have tried qmicli but that appears to only work if the driver is cdc-mdm whereas it is using qcserial. when connected, it generates /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/bus/usb/002/* which is a character unbuffered device file.

Comment: please provide some introducing stuff

Comment: @alecxs What information would you like to know?

Comment: https://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_tipo-4718.php is this the device you are trying to boot from? Where did you get the idea of booting from sdcard, and what is the reason/goal (what tutorial did you follow, link)? Which rom you trying to boot (download link)?

Comment: Nevermind, so you just asking about How to flash stock ROM without losing data? https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/general/xperia-tipo-st21i-official-thread-root-t2172652

Comment: I was not following a tutorial, I simply first thought I would try to lauch ArchLinuxArm on my phone, so I copied it from another sdcard to my phone's sdcard(ext_card). Tried to boot, but it booted as normal into android. I then set the boot flag on the arch partition. Still booted into android. Thought it would be due to boot order that it was not booting into arch, so I disabled the boot flag on the partition to boot into android. I then shut it down, whereupon it will not boot up again. Nothing happens when pressing and holding power or volume down; no LED when charging.

Comment: Would flashing a custom/stock ROM be able to restore my phone to a usable state without losing any user or app data, such as Whatsapp/Contacts? It is not detected by adb or fastboot on Mint or Arch.

Comment: So we are talking about hard bricked Snapdragon S1 right? I am afraid this device is not recoverable because it is too old. Search for Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader driver and Testpoint/EDL Mode. Find a flash tool (for example QPST) and a stock ROM for your device. I don't know how it works for Qualcomm devices, but for Mediatek devices it is possible to flash ROM without losing data

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2442917
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abzUMeVvlr8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7ewnsWVm34
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3748946
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/210156

Comment: @alecxs Although I haven't yet tried it, thankyou for your research. I would therefore like to award you the bounty, so please put an answer so that I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For booting from MicroSD card you need to heavily modify your ROM. The android boot partition is not like a PC BIOS. You need the bootloader to look at `mmcblk1` instead of `mmcblk0` which is hard-coded in various system files.
(for more information refer to Irfan Latif's documentation for QMobile Z8 on [forum.xda-developers.com](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/how-to-boot-sd-card-qmobile-z8-bricked-t3712171))

If your phone does not boot into fastboot mode it is hard bricked. Most devices have a emergency download mode from where you can repair your bootloader and flash ROM. For Qualcomm devices it is the EDL mode which can be reached via EDL mode cable/dongle or with a testpoint on the PCB circuit board.

For your old Xperia device you can use [Androxyde Flashtool](https://androidmtk.com/flash-sony-xperia-firmware)

For other Qualcomm devices use [QPST](https://androidmtk.com/use-qpst-flash-tool)

For MediaTek devices use [SP Flash Tool](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool)